# Is it possible to reliably detect a file upload in varnish?

Tags: http, varnish

I'm exploring routing all file uploads to a given backend in varnish. The obvious way to do this would be to match the urls that could be POST'ed to, but I also want to try and configure a catch-all that would route anything we missed in the url matching.

Is it possible to do this reliably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was thinking through the question, it occurred to me that checking for

```
req.http.Content-Type ~ "multipart/form-data"
```

in vcl_recv should be a reliable way to do this.

Edit: this appears to capture 90% of uploads in the context where I needed to do this.

Comment: We need to do something similar but with 100% reliability. What exactly did you mean by your edit?

Comment: The solution I provided is not 100% reliable with our application. I suspect this is because we don't have a single entry point for file uploads (the application is about 7 years old). YMMV.